# How can I use these Inductives without unsetting positivity checking in coq?

Tags: coq

To write in a straightforward way using `Inductive`, I have a code like below.

```
Inductive T :=
  | t0
  | t1 (a b : T)
  | ..
  | tk (P : T->Prop) (t : T)
  | tn (P : T->T->Prop) (t : T)
  | ..
  end
.
```

However, I have to `Unset Positivity Checking` to use `T`, and also cannot make a `Fixpoint` using this definition of `T`. I may use an alternative such as `bool` instead of `Prop`. This is just what my code looks like right now.

Is there a way to solve the issue using `Inductive` and not unsetting positivity checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot. Your type `T` is so large that it breaks the consistency of the logic.

```
Unset Positivity Checking.

Inductive T := tk (P : T -> bool).

Definition shaves x :=
  match x with tk f => f x end.

Definition barber :=
  tk (fun x => negb (shaves x)).

Goal False.
Proof.
assert (negb (shaves barber) = shaves barber).
{ change (negb (negb (shaves barber)) = shaves barber).
  now destruct shaves. }
now destruct shaves.
Qed.
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a fixpoint with this ill Inductive definition?

Comment: Sure. You can define fixpoints over any inductive type, whether well-formed or not. This inductive type has no positive occurrence, though, so fixpoints over it are trivial and thus pointless.